# More efficient web video stream on Rasberry Pi

Tags: motion

I am a surfer/kitesurfer and i live in the UAE. I'm trying to build a basic weather station that can provide wind and webcam details for a spot that is in a remote location. I am using a pi4 1GB and i am almost ready to install the station on site. My skills are fairly basic but this is where i am at:

1. pi4 runs ddns so it's dynamic address is accessible remotely with port forwarding - done
2. weewx uploads wind and weather info from the sensor to windguru - this is on track and will be done by the end of the week when a final part arrives
3. motion eye provides the video stream of camera 1 and camera 2 - done and visible from outside the LAN
4. Run apache/mysql/wordpress to provide a basic interface for people to check the info from their browser - almost done.

Now, regarding point 3... i am noticing that this is crippling the pi. Running nmon i can see each camera is utilising 110% of the CPU per camera. That is with minimal video streaming settings and a 1 fps rate. With both cameras running the pi is almost inaccessible through vnc or ssh and it gets very hot - i need to keep restarting it as it freezes.

I don't need a live stream, i'd be happy with an image every 30 seconds. Even if i disable video streaming and use the still image capture, 'motion' is still costing the CPU 110% per camera just to monitor it. Is there a better piece of software that i can be using?

I tried to edit sudo nano /etc/motion/motion.conf hoping to reduce the fps that motion uses to initialize the device but it doesn't affect the CPU usage.

Important to note, my camera is connected via IP and motion is connected to the device via RTSP://

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks, Sean.

Comment: Do you actually need the whole `motion` daemon in this case? It seems like it would be cheaper to just periodically capture directly from /dev/video.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if /dev/video can be used with an IP camera broadcasting the feed via RTSP ?